# Quorum cards like "Inspirational Speech" - Difference between results

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I just played my first game of BSG (solo using the official fully cooperative rules). I've got the german edition so my card names might be a bit off...

The card "Inspirational Speech" says something like:

**Action:** Roll dice. If you roll 6 or higher you get +1 Morale and this card is put out of play. Otherwise it has no effect and is discarded.

Now apart from gaining the 1 Morale, what is the difference of what happens with the card?

Comment: There are other cards that follow the same pattern: If you're lucky you gain something and put the card out of play. otherwise discard it. I can recall "Food Rationing" to work like this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Under "Component Limitations" it says that if the Quorum cards deck runs out you shuffle all discarded Quorum cards into a new deck.

Which means that if you fail the check you have a chance of getting the card again IF you manage to burn through the whole Quorum deck. If you succeed then the card won't come again.

Until now I just never considered that you might actually get to draw all the Quorum cards...

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a shot of the English version of the card that I've played with, but I think I remember the card you mean, and the Morale **is** the only difference.

The fact that the card is taken out of play means you only have a limited number of opportunities to gain back Morale in this way, so you have to hope you roll well.

Comment: Yes.  This is a way to use presidential powers to gain morale.  That is all, but that's still powerful.